# Dynamics Crm Create new account Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, dynamics-crm

```
mouse.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("name_i"))).Click().Build().Perform();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("name_i")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("name_i")).SendKeys("qwerty");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);


        //driver.FindElement(By.Id("name_i")).SendKeys("qwerty");
        //driver.FindElement(By.Id("telephone1_i")).SendKeys("555-555-5555");
        //driver.FindElement(By.Id("websiteurl_i")).SendKeys("https://www.google.com/");
```

I need some help with send keys to fields Account name, phone and website.
when I click new information dont wanna input data
selenium c#

Answer (score 0):

Try to use EasyRepro - https://github.com/Microsoft/EasyRepro 
This framework should address all your questions.

Comment: Have you downloaded mentioned solution and opened it with Visual Studio?